# Rendering 3 custom view in collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using `CollectionViewController` for rendering 3 custom view first and second is uiView which will use for showing image and third is grid.But Now problem is i am not able to render all three views one after another.Its overlapping on each other.Please help where i am doing wrong.I have to create same design for my app.

http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/59/10/fd/5910fd12-0721-9473-8001-8d3d16b22bdb/screen322x572.jpeg

And also check the my code .

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.section==0)

    {

        HeaderCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,200);
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor] ;

        return cell;
    }

    else if(indexPath.section==1)

    {

        HeaderCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,200);
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

        return cell;

    }

    else if(indexPath.section==2)

    {

        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }



    //   UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    // recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];

    // Configure the cell
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you probably need to change if you want that design.

I would start by forgetting about the UICollectionViewController business. Just set up a regular UIViewController and stick a UICollectionView in that. Here's code:

```
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
    flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0f;
    flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0f;
    flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;

    cv = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, w, h-40) collectionViewLayout:flow];
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self;
    cv.scrollEnabled = true;
    cv.bounces = true;
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
    cv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cv registerClass:[customCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
    [self.view addSubview:cv];
```

The w and h are just variables of the width and height of the screen.
You'll also need to add this to your header file:

```
<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

Now the CV wants to call the following methods, if it doesn't get them, it complains:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if(indexPath.section == 0){ 

    //then return a large cell size e.g.
    return CGSizeMake(320, 200);

  } else if (indexPath.section == 1) { 

    //then return a square grid size, e.g.
    return CGSizeMake(160, 160);

  }

 return CGSizeZero;

}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0) {
        return sectionZeroArray.count;
     } else ...     
}
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 3;
}
```

Including the cellForItem method, which is more for showing the content within the cell, normally hooked up to an array of data objects. You can't set sizes in there, like you have it now.

But looking at what you're trying to do re that design, it might be better, instead of splitting it up by section, to take advantage of the header and footers of the uicollectionview.

So you would just have one section, and within that you would have all your grid-sized square cells, and then up on the top bit you'd have a collectionview header, and within that, stick a UIScrollView with paging enabled, hooked up to a UIPageControl.

I don't know what you want to do re the third section at the bottom, but you could follow the same procedure as with the headerview, but as you wish of course.

If you've added all these methods and you're still struggling, post your code.